# How to insert a batch of empty rows without forloop?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table arts (
    `id` int(11) auto_increment,
    `pass` int,
    `name` varchar(255),
    `price` decimal(11,2),
    primary key (`id`)
) engine = innodb, charset utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_croatian_ci;
```

How can I insert `4000` empty rows inside the above table, using `mysql`?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: `Insert into arts (pass,name,price) values (null,null,null);` `Insert into arts (pass,name,price) select null,null,null from arts;` repeat the second insert 12 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `INSERT INTO` with `CROSS JOIN` ... `limit` your number.

```
INSERT INTO arts (pass,name,price)
SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1
CROSS JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  t2
LIMIT 4000
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66fbd/2/0)**:

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. I think - there is a shame for any language to be without any kind of `loop` or `range` in this case. Why not simply - `insert empty(4000)`